# ¿Cómo leer archivos en subcarpetas?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy complicado con un tema: se trata de una aplicación en Windows Forms en C# que me lea los archivo de una carpeta y también los archivos de subcarpetas de esa misma ruta.

Ya puedo leer los archivos de la carpeta a la que me apunta la ruta que le doy, ahora lo que me falta es  que me explore y lea los archivos de las subcarpetas. ¿Cómo podría hacer eso?

Aquí el código:

```
private void btnbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbxlista.Items.Clear();
    string ruta = @"" + txtruta.Text; //Escribir ruta
    string texto = txtfiltro.Text; //Escribir texto a buscar

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(ruta);

    foreach (var item in files)
    {
        string contenido = File.ReadAllText(item);

        if (contenido.Contains(texto))

            lbxlista.Items.Add(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿y si nos muestras código? te podríamos ayudar más fácil.

Answer (score 2):

Directory tienen tambien un metodo GetDirectories, que devuelve una lista de carpetas.

Como tenes que hacerlo recursivo esto, para a su vez acceder a cada carpeta que este dentro de las carpetas, tu mejor opcion es hacer una funcion recursiva que vaya rellenando ese lbxlista.

```
    private void btnbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbxlista.Items.Clear();
        string ruta = @"" + txtruta.Text; //Escribir ruta
        string texto = txtfiltro.Text; //Escribir texto a buscar
        //Aca llamarias a tu funcion que arrancaria.
        RecorrerCarpetas(ruta, texto);
    }

    RecorrerCarpetas(string r, string t)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(r);
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            string contenido = File.ReadAllText(item);

            if (contenido.Contains(t))

                lbxlista.Items.Add(item);
        }
        string[] carpetas = Directory.GetDirectories(r);
        foreach (var item in carpetas)
        {
                RecorrerCarpetas(item,t);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no quieres usar recursión tal como indica gbianchi, puedes usar:

`Directory.GetFiles(ruta, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Te devolverá todos los ficheros de la carpeta `"ruta"`, que cumplan la máscara `"*.*"` (es decir todos), e incluye los ficheros de las subcarpetas.

Comment: muchas gracias.. pero ahora como leo esos archivos

Comment: El resto de tu código es correcto, simplemente cambia tu `Directory.GetFiles(ruta)` por `Directory.GetFiles(ruta, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`, y listo.